# jquery confirm action doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I'm using this class to set up a Yes/No alert.

http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/

This is my code:

```
var currentId;

$(".confirm").click(function() {
    currentId = $(this).attr('id');
});

$(".confirm").confirm({
    text: "Are you sure?",
    confirm: function(button) {
                    //if I alert here currentId, it alerts right
        $.post("receive.php", { currentId: "id"} )
        .done(function(data) {
            alert(data); //NOTHING!!!
        });
    },
    cancel: function(button) {
        $('.modal hide fade').css("display", "none");
    },
    confirmButton: "Yes",
    cancelButton: "No!",
    post: true
});
});
```

**Receive.php**

```
<? echo $_POST['id']; ?>
```

Comment: You have one too many `});`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.post("receive.php", { currentId: "id"} )
```

should be

```
$.post("receive.php", { id: currentId } )
```

Comment: thank you! i thought that was fine but now i see i was wrong ;)